# Custom positioning for p:growl

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, growl

I am using `<p:growl>` component of PrimeFaces 3.2 to show faces messages. I would like to customize its position so that it appears on the left side instead of the right side.

I tried the following:

```
<h:head>
    <title>Facelet Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-growl {
            position:absolute;
            top:20px;
            left:20px;
            width:301px;
            z-index:9999;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="frm">
        <div id="add">
            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" >
            ...
```

But it did not work. Where was I wrong?

Comment: In the styling are'nt you missing position:relative or position:absolute?

Comment: edited my question...still the same problem...growl position isnt changing. where am i wrong?

Comment: @Kennet: Unnecessary. That's already in the default style of `p:growl`.

Comment: z22, which browser are you using?

Comment: @BaluC: m using firefox 7.0.1

Comment: while copying code from primefaces demos package statement also to be copied to your index jsf
Otherwise the demos may malfuntion

Answer (score 4):

Your code looks fine.

I copied it in my testcase and it works: the growl element shows on the upper left corner. For this only the `left:20px;` is necessary (thanks @BalusC for commenting).

So the problem must be somewhere else. Do you have additional style definitions for your page that you omitted in your example? Try to isolate the issue by removing all unnecessary stuff.

This is my testcase:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-growl{
                left:20px;
            }
        </style>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <h:form id="myform">
            <div id="add">
                <p:growl showDetail="true" sticky="true" autoUpdate="true"/>
            </div>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, only the `left` property has been sufficient. Others are identical as the default `.ui-growl` style.

Comment: @Matt Handy: thanks , yes i have additional styles defined, and when i remove the additional css the growl positioning works fine. but the additional css files are necessary for my app, and i also want the growl to work in customized way. what should i do?

Comment: Did you try `left:20px !important` ?

Comment: Another idea: Give the growl an id and try to modify the style with an id selector. It has precedence over the class style. But note that the generated id in the html source is different than the you define (e.g. if you define an id `growl` then he generated html id for the div is `growl_container`.

Comment: i tried   #growl{
                left:20px !important;
            }                                                                     still doesnt work

Comment: No, `growl` is not the client id. Check with firebug which is the correct one.

Comment: i checked in firebug it shows <span id="frm:growl"></span>           so i tried  #frm:growl{
                left:20px !important;
            }                                                         still not working... where am i getting wrong?

Comment: `left: 20px` is not sufficient, should also reset `right to somthing like `right: auto` or `right: `

Answer (score 2):

```
function growlLeft(){

                var css = document.createElement("style");
                css.id="growlStyle";
                css.type = "text/css";
                css.innerHTML = ".ui-growl { left: 20px!important}";
                document.body.appendChild(css);
            }
            function growlReset(){
                $('#growlStyle').empty();
            }
```

this code will help to positiongrowl dnamically and reset its positon. also the style class resolve the question which is

```
                 .ui-growl { left: 20px}
```

Comment: The `!important` is here a hack. You should remove it and make sure that your PrimeFaces override CSS file is loaded the right way. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/8774997/